# Should the rep limit be raised for access to admin tools?

Tags: discussion, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do about rep inflation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/what-to-do-about-rep-inflation)

Should the rep limit be raised for access to moderation tools? As the site's continue to grow more and more people will breech the 10k barrier(currently 100+ on SO). I'm not 100% sure that this is a problem, but is there ever a point where too many people having access to mod tools becomes a bad thing?

Comment: I think it should be... somewhere around 22,830.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/what-to-do-about-rep-inflation

Comment: @mmyers: 22,831 to be exact.

Comment: @John: 22830 to be on the safe side if it's checked with `>`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: You are a real programmer :)

Comment: The moderator tool for 10k users aren't  that powerful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is a duplicate but I'm too lazy to search.

To summarize the old discussions: Basically, as the number of questions increases, we need more moderation and we'll get more moderators and we'll end up having a stable moderator/post ratio. Increasing the threshold will reduce the moderator/post ratio.

Comment: Correct, but no upvote. I do not support laziness.