# Some thoughts about weighted scoring systems and tweaks to the calculation of scores to provide a more informative ranking order

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-rank, quality-score

Just looking at some trends of users and patterns of questions that have been asked, and I thought whether additional badges or weighted systems of scoring can be used for people who contribute very actively but don't get the credit that they probably deserve. For example, I for one think that it is important to ask difficult questions on this forum to help push the thinking in UX design further, yet if you ask a question that people find difficult to answer then it doesn't tend to get up voted as a 'popular' question. One potential solution might be to look at the ranking and reputation of the users that upvote or downvote questions to improve the outcome.

Also, some users generate a large 'momentum' by answering lots of questions, but due to being first to answer and just picking easier questions you can easily mistaken them to be very knowledgeable but in fact you need to dissect the questions and answers more carefully. So perhaps a different sorting or ordering system can be in place (e.g. most recent first) instead of the highest voted first because people will then tend to ignore the rest of the answers.

Lastly, users that have been on the site for a longer period of time benefit from the rankings due to accumulated points over a period of time, so perhaps so decay factor needs to be applied to reflect that they have not contributed actively or recently.

Comment: There are a number of concerns raised in your post, but not a lot of suggestions. Be careful not to let your post come across as a rant.

Comment: @mhlester very good point, and thanks for pointing it out. I have added some suggestions. What are your thoughts?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/what-to-do-about-rep-inflation