# When to upvote?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I upvote a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question)

I've been using stack overflow for a little while now, but I still consider myself a noob w/ noobish questions... like this one:

**When should I upvote an answer?**

*I'm asking about Stack Overflow, the meta faq makes it clear that you upvote on meta when you agree and downvote to disagree*

I know the mouseover text says "this answer is useful", but does that mean I should upvote it when:

1. The code works as an answer (even if its convoluted)
2. The code is elegant
3. The answerer put a lot of effort into researching the answer, even if the answer isn't fully correct/incomplete
4. The answer is hilarious, I mean like I'm falling out of my chair laughing funny :D
5. ...other people upvoted so I thought it was a good idea

Ok, now I'm just messing with you, but seriously, I'm at a loss for when to upvote; right now, I feel as if I've been upvoting too much.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Kinda, I was at a loss whether they were dupes, but this is asking about answer that is asking about questions...

Comment: Bah, meant to link this one:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/how-to-upvote-responsibly

Comment: Never for this reason: The answer is hilarious

Comment: Oh, I didn't find that when I was searching (odd O.o), but even so they are slightly different. My question being a bit broader

Comment: I always have a hard time finding specific info on meta, possibly because there are only a handful of applicable keywords that apply to a huge amount of posts.

Comment: @Wesley, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887107/are-regular-expressions-a-must-for-programming) disagrees with you on the upvoting for comic value thing :)

Comment: But, the answer is also useful and well formed, not just entertaining.

Comment: The answer is obviously "when 2 or 3 people have downvoted."