# Do upvotes and accepted answers tend to go toward the "celebrities" of SO?

Tags: discussion, reputation, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upvoting based on celebrity, too many upvotes (“excessive rep slurping”)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/upvoting-based-on-celebrity-too-many-upvotes-excessive-rep-slurping)

Maybe this is a hard one, if not impossible, to quantify. But it seems like reputation builds reputation. Or maybe it's just a matter of asking (and answering) the right questions. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Just ask anyone who has answered the same question Jon Skeet has.

(to be clear, this is tongue-in-cheek, he gets his reputation because he provides excellent answers)

Comment: Indeed. My proudest achievement on SO is that I have more votes than Jon Skeet on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235025/why-should-unit-tests-test-only-one-thing/ Now if I only my answer was marked accepted, my happiness would be complete.