# Show user reputation when item was posted

Tags: feature-request, reputation, revisions-list

As I suggested in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345/theoretical-question-hide-rep-above-10k/703#703), I am **not** in favor of **rewriting History**.

Or, the rep score shown next to a user is always the *current* one. It would be quite interesting to have the one *at the posting time*.

It may be in brackets, or in a tooltip in order no to be intrusive and to preserve the spirit of what is displayed currently : how the user is recognized **now** by the system.

Answer (score 5):

It's a form of information pornography; but yes, it is useful for all manner of number crunching and following users and their trek through the system. That's what I like about the idea -- that you could then have time-based metrics to solve all sorts of issues:

1. What percentage of 'new' users ask Subjective questions?
2. How does the nature of questions change as a user gets higher in rank?

Right now you could determine that through a lot of time-based analysis, but it would be complex. It would be nice to have this information de-normalized, even if just a tooltip when hovering over the question asker's name.

Comment: Or simply just include it in the data dump but never display it.

Comment: @andreas can you just cross reference the rep graph against the time posted date?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this via a SEDE query. Something [like this perhaps](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507404/score-at-time-of-post).

```
select sum(score) + 1
from
(select count(*) * p.posttypeid * 5 score
from posts p 
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
inner join posts p2 on p2.owneruserid = p.owneruserid
where p2.id = ##postid?8092417##
and v.votetypeid = 2
and p.creationdate < p2.creationdate
and v.creationdate < p2.creationdate
and p.posttypeid in (1, 2)
group by p.posttypeid
union all
select count(*) * -2
from posts p 
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
inner join posts p2 on p2.owneruserid = p.owneruserid
where p2.id = ##postid?8092417##
and v.votetypeid = 3
and p.creationdate < p2.creationdate
and v.creationdate < p2.creationdate
and p.posttypeid in (1, 2)
group by p.posttypeid) t
```

It doesn't cope with bounties but it should give an approximate score at the time of the post by counting votes received prior to the time of the post.