# Two kinds of vote

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Propose two types of upvote:

- **Normal upvote**.  Current upvote.  Has the meaning "This answer is helpful"
- **I like that**.  This kind of upvote means the answer is pleasing somehow, but not necessarily technically rewarding.  "I like that" votes add to a user's charisma score, not their reputation.  Community wiki answers can earn charisma points, so it makes posting answers to Community wikis "more worthwhile".  It will be harder to claim that the system unfairly rewards "celebrities", if the charisma vote is used correctly.

I know this suggestion is likely to be thought 'bulky', but it will give the site an additional dimension.  Someone that gives "good" answers will be distinct from someone that gives clever or snarky answers that the rest of the community simply enjoys reading.

This suggestion is similar to

- [Celebrity and upvote "slurping"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/upvoting-based-on-celebrity-too-many-upvotes-excessive-rep-slurping)
- [Rep inflation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/what-to-do-about-rep-inflation)
- [Hide rep above 10k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345/theoretical-question-hide-rep-above-10k)
- [Reputation attracts too many upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-up-votes)
- [anonymous questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198)

Comment: -1 I don't think this should be separated. There is a reason why reputation and community wiki's exists. I vote because I like an answer and want someone to gain reputation, however I don't see a reason to get reputation for an opinion.

Comment: That is the point - good opinions would win another type of piont / score.  I called it "charisma" here but it could be called anything else.

Comment: I have to agree with Spencer on this one. It's complicated. This is not social networking. This is a Q&A site dealing with right and wrong answers. Reputation has already caused some interesting attitudes and gaming, no need to complicate it further.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds complicated.

Comment: I like that answer but it's not rewarding to me.