# Is there a humor Q&A in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, humor

I want to ask some funny things (humor questions) but I don't know where. Is there an appropriate Q&A site in Stack Exchange?

Maybe not only humor, but we all known memes. Why don't have a site about new science called "Memology"?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295897/require-multiple-downvotes-to-flag-low-quality-questions-rework-system-to-encou?noredirect=1#comment960062_295897 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes/31166#comment960047_31166 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248218/dissuading-trolls-increase-reputation-cost-for-downvote-on-answers#comment960042_248218 The Stack Exchange Politburo doesn't appreciate humor or any other content that disagrees with them. Crooked, crooked, crooked! I recommend moving to Quora.

Comment: Also I wonder what answers we should reply at _humor questions_, _LOL_, _ROTFL_, etc.?? Doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I guess, I'll never visit Quora again then.

Comment: @Eugen You could try Reddit alternatively ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Yeah, that's a better decision.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

Comment: @gnat: Uh, no, it's asking about a site that *explains* humor. Not a site *for* funny jokes.

Comment: @gnat Seriously, gnat, you need to stop closing questions as a duplicate of that one, which answers absolutely nothing. It's a feature request for a subjective subdomain of each site. It's totally unhelpful and unrelated to almost all of the questions you keep closing it as a dupe as. Even as a future signpost is fails miserably. I don't understand why you're stuck on that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't. The [Humor proposal was closed](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24036/the-closing-of-humor) before ever being allowed to enter beta and it's unlikely that it will get created in the future.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. That's good and bad both ways. It's bad because all trolls (prankers and all of them) will be there.

Comment: @EugenEray I dunno why you think these kind of people would stay away from the main sites, if such place would exist?