# Questions on the featured page should be listed in order of bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please give us the ability to sort “featured” tab by bounty amount](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7753/please-give-us-the-ability-to-sort-featured-tab-by-bounty-amount)

Bountys should be seen as a sacrifice to get a good answer,at least that's what the answer in this question says. ([How about a separate private "bounty points" *alongside* your public "reputation points"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9))

That is true, but there's not much an advantage of spending 500 rep over 50 because on the featured page there doesn't seem any order and a question with 500 bounty can be hidden on the 3rd page while a 50 bounty question is right at the top of the first question.

It makes more sense for question with 500 to be at the top, and the sorted by the number of answers within each bounty segment. So a question with 500 bounty and 0 answers is at the top, while a question 500 bounty and 1 answer is just below it

Comment: There is an ordering.  The current ordering is done by time left on the bounty.

Comment: This is not asking for the ability to sort, but for the default sort to be changed. Well some kind of formula should be made where in general its based on time left, but higher bounties get an advantage. EG a question with 500 rep and ends in 2 days is shown higher up than a 50 bounty question with one day left.

Comment: Here's a script to give an option: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252238/260841